# Rename key in a mongoDB array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to rename the key "street" to "block" in every object of the "address" array in a mongo document. The structure of the document is as follows,

```json
    {
      "_id": 1234,
      "name": "Jack",
      "address": [
        {
          "no": 1,
          "street": "streetx",
          "country": "countryx"
        },
        {
          "no": 1,
          "street": "streety",
          "country": "countryy"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Note : The mongoDB version is '4.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$map` to assign the new field to the address objects. For MongoDB v4.0, use javascript to iterate and update back to the collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "address": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$address",
          "as": "a",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$a",
              {
                "no": "$$a.no",
                "country": "$$a.country",
                "block": "$$a.street"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).forEach(function(doc){
  db.collection.save(doc);
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qGFTgHT2--x) for your reference.

Comment: $unset is not available in mongo 4.0.0. It is throwing an error "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$unset'"

Comment: @VinayGowda updated the answer to use simple `$map` only